# Object created on the heap is not global?

Tags: c++, memory, default-constructor, global-object

I read a book S. Lippman "inside c++ object model", is there such code

```
class Foo { public: int val; Foo *pnext; };
void foo_bar()
{
// Oops: program needs bar's members zeroed out
Foo bar;
Foo* baz = new Foo(); // this line i added myself
if ( bar.val || bar.pnext )
// ... do something
// ...
}
```

and it says that
"A default constructor is not synthesized for this code fragment.

Global objects are guaranteed to have their associated memory "zeroed out" at program start-up. Local objects
allocated on the program stack and heap objects allocated on the free-store do not have their associated memory
zeroed out; rather, the memory retains the arbitrary bit pattern of its previous use."

In this code the baz object  was created on the heap, and according to what has been said above this object is not global and it will not be called the default constructor. I understand correctly ?

Comment: It is not global, but its values *will* be zeroed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses in `new Foo()` specify *value initialisation*; this basically means that each member is zero-initialised. If instead you said `new Foo`, then the members would be left uninitialised, as they are for your automatic variable.

Unfortunately, to value-initialise the automatic variable, you can't write `Foo bar()`, since that declares a function. You'll need

```
Foo bar{};        // C++11
Foo bar = Foo();  // Historical C++
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
Foo* baz = new Foo();
```

you are dynamically allocating a `Foo` instance and *value-initializing* it. For PODs, this means the members get zero-initialized. If you had said this (assuming non-global context):

```
Foo* baz = new Foo;
```

then the `Foo` instance would be default initialized, which would mean no initialization of its members is performed, since they are PODs.

This also applies to automatic storage instances:

```
Foo f0; // default initializaiton: members not zeroed out.
Foo f1 = Foo(); // value initialization: members zeroed out.
Foo f2{}; // C++11 value initialization: members zeroed out.
Foo f3(); // Ooops! Function declaration. Something completely different.
```

Comment: It should be noted however that this value-initialization is a C++11 addition. Before, as far as I know, the empty parentheses had no special meaning and would just as well execute the default constructor which does nothing, right?

Answer (score 0):

If a class have no default constructor (and no other constructor), the compiler will create one for you. It has to, or you would not be able to create instances of the class. However, the generated default constructor will not do anything.

What adding the empty set of parentheses in `new Foo()` does, is to value initialize the allocated object, which means the members gets initialized to their "default" values, which is zero for integer and floating point values, and `nullptr` for pointers.